# Limit of Function

Tags: limits

If $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2} \frac {f(x)-5}{x-2}=3$, find $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2} f(x)$.

This is what I have so far.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2} \frac {f(x)-5}{x-2} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 2}\left(f(x) \cdot \frac{1}{x-2}\right)-\frac{5}{x-2}$$

Is this right? What do I do next?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't split it up that way, as $\frac{5}{x - 2}$ doesn't approach anything finite as $x \to 2$, so it's not going to help you apply algebra of limits.

Instead, try expressing:

$$f(x) = \frac{f(x) - 5}{x - 2} \cdot (x - 2) + 5$$

and applying algebra of limits. We get

$$f(x) \to 3 \cdot 0 + 5 = 5.$$

Answer (score 3):

I would argue this way: the denominator is going to zero. For the overall initial limit to be finite, what would the numerator have to approach? And what does that say about the desired limit?

Comment: This is of course not an answer

Comment: @Neymar it directly leads to the answer however. Sometimes a hint is better than the whole thing.